# Posso conectar em um banco de dados usando JS?

Tags: mysql

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site para mim e gostaria de saber se consigo usar o JavaScript para se conectar no banco de dados e pegar um valor.

OBS:O site é local mesmo, e o banco também e estão na minha máquina, vocês sabem se posso me conectar usando JS ? Como?

Comment: Eu gosto de pensar que javascript nunca poderia se conectar ao banco de dados por questões de segurança, já imaginou que você pode vim no site da hotmail e invadir o banco de dados pelo navegador? Bom, é estranho, mas javascript roda no navegador e por isso que eu acredito que é impossivel esta linguagem fornecer(e porque não o navegador) acessibilidade ao servidor do site(ou servidor do banco de dados).. Acho que uma coisa parecida com banco de dados(embora bem diferente), é o localstorage(html5) que oferece a oportunidade de gravar informações do usuário, mas não de forma permanente.

Answer (score 1):

O javascript deve ser usado única e exclusivamente para o lado do cliente, mais precisamente no sandbox do navegador.

Para se comunicar com o banco de dados inevitavelmente você vai precisar trabalhar com alguma linguagem server side. Eu pessoalmente indico o PHP nestes casos, pois tem dependência quase nula e a maioria dos servidores web o têm por padrão.

Answer (score 0):

No MySQL 5.7 tem o HTTP Plugin com o qual poderá fazer o que pretende. Há outros meios também, mas esse é o mais conhecido. O plugin é basicamente uma REST API.

Outro meio é usando ActiveXObject, conectando pelo ADODB ODBC. Claro que nesse caso o browser deve possuir permissões liberadas para acesso ao objeto ActiveX.